# Dropzone drag and drop overlapping onto Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dropzone.js

I just implemented the advice shared in this tutorial on integrating dropzone with other form fields as part of one full form. https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

The issue that i am having now is that the form upload space where an image is dragged is now overlapping the entire form: [image: image of this]

This is the form code that i have for this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url("dropzone/upload");?>" class='dropzone'>
                <!--<form role="form">-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="example-subscription-email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="example-subscription-email" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="example-subscription-password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="example-subscription-password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Get Better Photos!</button>
                    <!--<a href="#share" class="btn btn-lg btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> Share</a>
                    <a href="#share" class="btn btn-lg btn-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i> Share</a>-->
                </form>
```

Comment: Can you put this into a jsfiddle? I think one would need to see all your CSS and javascript to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As i was trying to instantiate dropzone on non-form elements, i had to define the destination url in dropzone.js.

Like this:

```
var u = window.location.hostname; 

Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
  url: u + 'dropzone/upload',
```

This solved the problem.

Now i have this:

[image]